# Library to mock nodejs object base on flow typing

Tags: node.js, mocking, flowtype

I'm looking for a JS library to mock object base of my type declaration.

For example this is my user type:

```
export type UserType = {
    id: string,
    userId: string,
    platform: ?string,
    gender: ?string,
    timezone: ?number,
    picture_url: ?string,
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    locale: ?string,
    created_on: ?Date
};
```

I want to be able to do that: `let userMock = mock(UserType)`

do you know something that allow to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typescript, you can use [Factory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/factory.ts) to generate factories for test data for Typescript based on the interface provided.

For a normal js, you can utilize [Faker](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) which provides a good tool to generate random test data.